# Combining CSS transition and animation in Firefox

Tags: css, firefox, animation, css-transitions

Here is [my CodePen](https://codepen.io/f3d/pen/YVqaLO) that works fine in Chrome.

```css
.animated-box {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 10px auto;
  background: black;
  border-radius: 50px;
  transition-duration: 0.2s;
}

.animated-box:hover {
  border-radius: 18px;
  animation-name: test;
  animation-duration: 0.7s;
  animation-delay: 0.2s;
}

@keyframes test {
  0% {
    border-radius: 18px;
  }
  12% {
    border-radius: 15px;
  }
  41% {
    border-radius: 21px;
  }
  70% {
    border-radius: 16px;
  }
  100% {
    border-radius: 18px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="animated-box"></div>
```

But there is a problem in Firefox.
It doesn't play the animation if there are both CSS transition and CSS animation properties.
How to make it work?

Making "out" animation to `.animated-box` selector is wrong solution because this animation will play after page loading.

Here is [a video](https://monosnap.com/file/mpLUhilXgspjDcJJp1R2vgNTYf6vLI) comparing the result in Firefox and Chrome.

Comment: Well, your `transition-delay` doesn't do any thing so I don't get why it is there? ... If you want to do both transition and animation, put all code in first, before we can have a say why or how to make it work

Comment: its working on firefox as well.. which version of firefox its not working?

Comment: `transition-delay` used to make "bounce" effect after transition from circle to square ends

Comment: my firefox version is 52.0.2 (64-bit)
Works only "out" transtition, "in" transition doesnt work

Comment: But you can't expect to have a transition without actually set the property like `transition: border-radius 1s`

Comment: `transition: border-radius 1s` same effect with this. No "in" transition

Comment: The effect  is more visible if you increase animation-delay to 1s. But it is working ok for me in FF.

Comment: @vals which firefox version and OS you are use?

Comment: I have tested it in an old version (49) on Win 7

Answer (score 2):

The specification is not entirely clear on what should happen, so I believe that both Firefox and Chrome are technically adhering to it. **The safest fix is to not use a combination of transition and animation, but instead do everything in the animation**. I'll give a demo of that below.

**Background**
The [specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-animations/#animations) has a helpful figure that illustrates that during the animation delay, the intrinsic style of the element should be applied. This style is transitioned by you.

[image: Figure 1 in CSS3 animations specification: illustration of animation style]

Now the specification states that

> The values used for the keyframes and animation properties are snapshotted at the time the animation starts. Changing them during the execution of the animation has no effect.

It looks like Firefox (at least on Linux) snapshots the value right *after* the hover effect is applied and then uses that as the intrinsic style. This means that no transition is applied. Chrome does indeed execute the transition, treating that as the intrinsic style.

**Cross-browser working solution**
Instead of doing a transition first and then an animation, we can do everything in the animation. I have calculated how the keyframes should shift and updated your animation. This achieves the effect you were seeing in Chrome in Firefox as well.

```css
.animated-box {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 10px auto;
  background: black;
  border-radius: 50px;
}

.animated-box:hover {
  border-radius: 18px;
  animation-name: test;
  animation-duration: 0.9s;
}

@keyframes test {
  0% {
    border-radius: 50px;
  }
  22% {
    border-radius: 18px;
  }
  32% {
    border-radius: 15px;
  }
  54% {
    border-radius: 21px;
  }
  77% {
    border-radius: 16px;
  }
  100% {
    border-radius: 18px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="animated-box"></div>
```

Comment: To make it look really good you might want to alter the sequence some and change last value to `100% { border-radius: 50px; }` ... still, plus 1

Comment: @LGSon Agreed, I just wanted to stick to what OP has as closely as possible.

Comment: Got that, though as OP has the transition property set on the non hovered class, that means it should apply on both mouse over and out. If you check the original codepen on Chrome, you'll see it does that

Comment: @LGSon Good point. To really get that, I suppose I should keep the transition then... OP also indicated that the animation will run on page load, so I'll refrain from cluttering my answer and leave it as is. Upvoted your comment for visibility though :-)